# ctypes, python3.8 : OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000

Tags: python, c, ctypes

i want to run a dll via python 3.8
i have a function in my dll part which is :

```
void DLLAPI __stdcall GenerateReport (
    int             SeqContext,
    char*           szHost,
    char*           szDBName,
    char*           szUser,
    char*           szPasswd,
    const char*     szUut_Result_Id,
    char            szStylesheet[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN],
    char            szDestinationDir[MAX_DIRNAME_LEN],
    char            szPrefix[MAX_FILENAME_LEN],
    char            szFileName[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN],
    char            szPathName[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN],
    short*          psErrorOccurred,
    long*           plErrorCode,
    char            szErrorMessage[1024]
    );
```

For a python part i did like this :

```
def PrintReport():
    szNom_PV_Court = ''
    szErrormessage = ''
    sErrorok = 0
    lErrorcode = 0

    worker_ = cdll.LoadLibrary("D:\\users\\Worker.dll")

    if (worker_ == 0):
        print( " Could not open file DLL")

    worker_.GenerateReport( 0, "localhost" ,  "backend" , "user" , "test12", str( Uut_Result_Id ) , "D:\\users\\py\\ResourceFiles\\Gen.xsl" , "D:\\users\\py","" ,szNom_PV_Court , "D:\\users\\py" ,sErrorok ,lErrorcode ,szErrormessage )
```

when i execute my code i get error : OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000

I'dont understand this error please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings like `"localhost"` in Python 3 are Unicode strings and translated to `wchar_t*` by ctypes.  Use `b'localhost'` for byte strings that are translated to `char*`.

Also, define `.argtypes` and `.restype` for your function to for ctypes to marshal your parameters properly:

```
worker_.argtypes = c_int,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_char_p,POINTER(c_short),POINTER(c_long),c_char_p
worker_.restype = None
```

You also only have 13 parameters in your call but 14 are defined for the function.

Use the following for the `short*` and `long*` to create instances that can be passed to the call.  Right now you are passing a zero as the default `c_int` which is probably the source of the null pointer exception.

```
sErrorok = c_short()
lErrorcode = c_long()
```

Call using `byref(sErrorok)` and `byref(lErrorcode)` to pass to the call as pointers.

Here's a complete example.  I skipped the many input strings and just show one for reference:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DLLAPI __declspec(dllexport)

void DLLAPI __stdcall GenerateReport (
    int             SeqContext,
    char*           szHost,
    short*          psErrorOccurred,
    long*           plErrorCode,
    char            szErrorMessage[1024]
    )
{
    printf("SeqContext = %d szHost = %s\n",SeqContext,szHost);
    *psErrorOccurred = 5;
    *plErrorCode = 123;
    strcpy_s(szErrorMessage,1024,"error message");
}
```

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *

szNom_PV_Court = ''
szErrormessage = ''
sErrorok = 0
lErrorcode = 0

dll = WinDLL('./test.dll')
dll.GenerateReport.argtypes = c_int,c_char_p,POINTER(c_short),POINTER(c_long),c_char_p
dll.GenerateReport.restype = None

err_occurred = c_short()
errcode = c_long()
errmsg = create_string_buffer(1024)

dll.GenerateReport(7,b'localhost',byref(err_occurred),byref(errcode),errmsg)
print(err_occurred.value,errcode.value,errmsg.value.decode())
```

**Output:**

```
SeqContext = 7 szHost = localhost
5 123 error message
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but szErrormessage still empty when i want to print the message. i think it's related for declaration var. i did like this szErrormessage = "" and for generateReport function i did c_char_p( szErrormessage.encode('utf-8') ) but when i want to print print( szErrormessage.encode('utf-8') ) the answer still empty

Comment: Is it : szErrormessage = c_char_p() for declaration like you did for sErrorok and lErrorcode ?

Comment: @TheRight `szErrormessage = create_string_buffer(1024)` will allocate a buffer for the return string.  `szErrormessage = c_char_p()` will allocate a pointer initialized to NULL.  Any other output string should have memory allocated for it as well.

Comment: For declaration i did like you said : szErrormessage = create_string_buffer(1024) and for generateReport method i let like GenerateReport(....,szErrormessage). But when i print ( szErrormessage ) , The output is : <ctypes.c_char_Array_1024 object at 0x055455C8>. it needs a message decode or how ?

Comment: @TheRight Updated answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You hadn't filled all strings for DLL, so they was initialized to zero. Your dll is trying to read from address 0x0 (zero) and getting smacked by OS for this. Fill all required fields with proper values.